# C++ Threads Not Running Simultaneously

Tags: c++, multithreading

First of all, I am not an expert at threading so if there is a very obvious mistake in my code, please correct it instead of bantering.

I have a vector of objects, each having its own initialisation parameters. What I want to achieve is to call same function of each object with different parameters (everything stored in a vector of structures). I thought, doing the following will achieve it:

```
vector<thread> vThreads;        
for (int k = 0; k < vObjs.size(); k++)      
{
     vThreads.push_back(std::thread(&CEllipseDetector::Detect, vObjs[k].objYaed, vObjs[k].gray.clone(), vObjs[k].ellipses));        
}
```

EllipseDetector is the class name and I'm trying to call its function Detect and passing two parameters gray.clone() and ellipses.

Now I was assuming that once I make these threads, they will start their execution, but they don't. Checking the Resource Monitor, threads are indeed created but they (or I should say just one of them) only start execution when I write the following:

```
for (int k = 0; k < vThreads.size(); k++)
{
    vThreads[k].join();

   //Some other stuff here//
}
```

What I was hoping to achieve was that in the first loop, all the threads will start their execution independently and in the second loop, I will catch them when they finish execution, one by one.. Do some post processing on their objects and that's it...

But what's happening is that, as soon as it hits the first join call, only then all the threads start execution 'one by one'.

I hope I made my problem clear "calling the function simultaneously using threads and then knowing when they have finished execution to do some post processing. Maybe, just like a callback function?

One last thing: If I use .detach instead of join, then all the threads do run simultaneously and finish together, but the problem then is that I cannot do the post processing.

Comment: Without knowing `CEllipseDetector::Detect` does it is hard to tell

Comment: I'm not sure how knowing that will make a difference.. Let's say it adds two numbers..

Comment: Does it have semaphores? Perhaps one is waiting for the other to do something?

Comment: Have you tried replacing it with something that just adds two numbers?

Comment: No, they are independent of each other, when I use .detach instead of join, they do run simultaneously and finish together.

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Are you sure you're calling thread and not std::async?  Of course, there's never any guarantee as to when a thread will run.  Forcing the current thread to block by calling join() is going to encourage the OS to run another thread.